# whats the probability of a number getting picked from a pool fewer than 3 times?

Tags: probability, statistics

Picking from a pool of 20000 different numbers, each experiment we pick 1000 different numbers(one numbers can be picked repeatedly in different experiments but not in the same experiment), and we pick n times(n experiments).whats the probability that at least  one number is picked fewer than 3 times in the entire n experiments?

From What I got, the probability of a number in this pool getting picked at least once is (1-the probability of this number never getting picked).

So In Experiment 1, the probability of this number not getting picked is 19/20.

In Experiment 2, the probability of this number not getting picked is (19/20)^2

So the probability of this number not getting picked at experiment n is (19/20)^n

And that's what I got if just at least 1, what if we change that to 2 or 3 or d?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You will get a lot more help and a lot fewer down votes if you show that you've made an honest effort to do the problem.  What have you done so far?  Where are you stuck?  Please note that a question with no more context than you have given is likely to be closed by the moderators.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is my first post so please bear with any mistakes that I might have made. I have modified my question and expressed how far I went with my question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  When you say "picked fewer than 3 times" do you mean picked in fewer than $3$ experiments or $3$ times in total?  If $7$ is picked $3$ times in the first experiment, and never picked again, does that count as getting picked three times?

Comment: Thanks for noticing this vague expression, I have modified the question, what I mean is that say there is a number 7, this 7 can appear once or zero times in one experiment, what is the probability that this 7 is picked less than 3 times in total in the entire n experiments.

Comment: If you want the probability that a specific number $x$ is picked < 3 times, that is pretty easy: In any experiment, $x$ is picked with Prob = 1/20 so this is just like flipping a (highly biased) coin $n$ times and seeing how many heads appear.  This is called a Bernoulli process; you can look it up.  However, if you want the probability that AT LEAST ONE NUMBER (among 20000 numbers) being picked < 3 times that seems a (much) harder problem.  E.g., if $n<60$ then you pick < 60000 numbers total, so some of the 20000 will certainly have been picked < 3 times.  Is the latter what you want?

Comment: Yes! the later is exactly what I am struggling with, for the problem I am facing, I am trying to determine a n value that makes most numbers get picked at least 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

If the counting is cumulative, then there is no point in segregating the picks between experiments.  We simply make $1,000n$ choices.  It is not correct to divide $1,000$ by $20,000.$  That would be right if we picked without replacement, that is, if a number can only be picked once.  Then we pick $1,000$ numbers, and look to see if the designated number is among them.  Then also, it make sense to take about $n$ experiments, because we would replace the $1,000$ numbers at the end of the experiment.

Now for the actual question.  It seems to me like you're taking about a specific number.  That is, you're asking something like, "What is the probability that $7$ gets picked fewer than $3$ times?," not "What is the probability that some number among all $20,000$ gets picked fewer than $3$ times?"

The probability that $7$ is not picked on a particular draw is $\frac{19999}{20000}=.99995.$  To make things easier to type, and top read, set $p=.9995, N=1000n.$  The probability that $7$ is never picked is $p^N.$  What about the probability that $7$ is picked exactly once?  There are $N$ ways to select which draw $7$ will be picked on, and the probability that $7$ will be picked on that draw is $1-p$.  Then $7$ isn't picked on any of the remaining $N-1$ draws, so the probability that $7$ is picked on exactly one draw is $N(1-p)p^{N-1}.$

To finish it off, you need to compute the probability that $7$ is picked on exactly $2$ draws, and add up the three probabilities.